# Ruby - Order Array of Hashes By Group

Tags: ruby, hash, grouping

```
data = [{'id' => 1, 'num' => 10},
        {'id' => 1, 'num' => 5},
        {'id' => 1, 'num' => 8},
        {'id' => 2, 'num' => 0},
        {'id' => 2, 'num' => 20},
        {'id' => 2, 'num' => -5},
        {'id' => 5, 'num' => 9},
        {'id' => 5, 'num' => 9}]
```

I want to order this information by groups of the same `id` according to the max `num` associated with each group of `id`.  Then within each group, the `num` can also be used for further ordering.

```
data_transformed = 
            [{'id' => 2, 'num' => 20},
            {'id' => 2, 'num' => 0},
            {'id' => 2, 'num' => -5},
            {'id' => 1, 'num' => 10},
            {'id' => 1, 'num' => 8},
            {'id' => 1, 'num' => 5},
            {'id' => 5, 'num' => 9},
            {'id' => 5, 'num' => 9}]
```

This would also be fine

```
data_transformed = 
            [[{'id' => 2, 'num' => 20},
            {'id' => 2, 'num' => 0},
            {'id' => 2, 'num' => -5}],

            [{'id' => 1, 'num' => 10},
            {'id' => 1, 'num' => 8},
            {'id' => 1, 'num' => 5}],

            [{'id' => 5, 'num' => 9},
            {'id' => 5, 'num' => 9}]]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do :

```
data = [{'id' => 1, 'num' => 10},
        {'id' => 1, 'num' => 5},
        {'id' => 1, 'num' => 8},
        {'id' => 2, 'num' => 0},
        {'id' => 2, 'num' => 20},
        {'id' => 2, 'num' => -5},
        {'id' => 5, 'num' => 9},
        {'id' => 5, 'num' => 9}]

data_grouped_ordered_by_num = data.group_by { |h| h['id'] }.sort_by { |_,v| v.map { |h| h['num'] }.max }.reverse
# => [[2, [{"id"=>2, "num"=>0}, {"id"=>2, "num"=>20}, {"id"=>2, "num"=>-5}]],
#     [1, [{"id"=>1, "num"=>10}, {"id"=>1, "num"=>5}, {"id"=>1, "num"=>8}]],
#     [5, [{"id"=>5, "num"=>9}, {"id"=>5, "num"=>9}]]]

data_grouped_ordered_by_num.map { |k,v| v.sort_by {|h| -h['num']} }
# => [[{"id"=>2, "num"=>20}, {"id"=>2, "num"=>0}, {"id"=>2, "num"=>-5}],
#     [{"id"=>1, "num"=>10}, {"id"=>1, "num"=>8}, {"id"=>1, "num"=>5}],
#     [{"id"=>5, "num"=>9}, {"id"=>5, "num"=>9}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data.group_by{ |x| x['id'] }.values.map do |x|
  x.sort_by do |y| 
    -y['num']
  end 
end

#=> [[{"id"=>1, "num"=>10}, {"id"=>1, "num"=>8}, {"id"=>1, "num"=>5}],
 [{"id"=>2, "num"=>20}, {"id"=>2, "num"=>0}, {"id"=>2, "num"=>-5}],  
 [{"id"=>5, "num"=>9}, {"id"=>5, "num"=>9}]]
```

You can use `flatten` after that to flat the result which will give you your first desired output:

```
[{"id"=>1, "num"=>10},
 {"id"=>1, "num"=>8},
 {"id"=>1, "num"=>5},
 {"id"=>2, "num"=>20},
 {"id"=>2, "num"=>0},
 {"id"=>2, "num"=>-5},
 {"id"=>5, "num"=>9},
 {"id"=>5, "num"=>9}]
```

Comment: If you run some benchmarks , you'll find that using `reverse` on the result of `sort_by` is faster than using the negated value in the `sort_by` block. Also, by convention we use `{...}` instead of a do/end block with `sort_by`.

Answer (score 1):

```
data.sort_by { |h| [h['id'], -h['num']] } 
  #=> [{'id' => 1, 'num'=>10}, {'id'=>1, 'num'=>8}, {'id'=>1, 'num'=> 5},
  #    {'id' => 2, 'num'=>20}, {'id'=>2, 'num'=>0}, {'id'=>2, 'num'=>-5},
  #    {'id' => 5, 'num'=> 9}, {'id'=>5, 'num'=>9}]
```

For the second format:

```
data.sort_by { |h| [h['id'], -h['num']] }.chunk { |h| h['id'] }.map(&:last)
  #=> [[{"id"=>1, "num"=>10}, {"id"=>1, "num"=>8}, {"id"=>1, "num"=> 5}],
  #    [{"id"=>2, "num"=>20}, {"id"=>2, "num"=>0}, {"id"=>2, "num"=>-5}],
  #    [{"id"=>5, "num"=> 9}, {"id"=>5, "num"=>9}]]
```

[Array#sort_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21) uses [Array#<=>](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) for comparisons.  Documentation for the latter explains why this produces the desired result.